# If you get "The directory name is invalid", is there a general way to display which directory?

Tags: c#, exception

I am presently programming a winform application in C#.

I am always a little annoyed as user when I get this exception. If the system throws this exception, why does it not tell me which directory it is talking about? Is there a way to change this error message generally. Always, for all situations. It would be far more useful if the user would get a message like: The directory name "C:\IdoNotExist" is invalid.

The behavior is probably deep down in windows though, I fear, right?

Comment: You know about _try - catch_ blocks? How is the exception caused? Can you give a code example?

Comment: You are right of course KB, but then I have to do that for all programs, all situations. Is there some general, setting or something? Probably not, I know. Yes, EvilFonti, of course I can work this out. Just looking for something more general. I also wonder why windows does not display the directory name itself. Maybe that is for security and not giving information to hackers?

Comment: No, the behavior isn't deep down in windows at all. When you program an application and you ask the OS to look up the directory "XYZ", the OS will tell you that the directory does not exist. You as a programmer know exactly which directory does not exist. And you also know better than showing an exception directly to the user. From an API perspective, including the name of the directory into the exception string doesn't offer an advantage, but it offers risk of doing it wrong as soon as invalid or non-printable characters are involved.

Comment: What IO-methods are you using at all? If i use `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\IdoNotExist");` i'm getting: _"System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\IdoNotExist'"_ which contains the name of the directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you can predict an incorrect input from user, it's better to avoid handling it with the exceptions. You can test the directory name with the

```
Directory.Exists("[given_directory_name]")
```

and show the user appropriate message.

Comment: That's a race condition. I prefer opening the directory/file and just check what kind of failure message I get if it fails.

Comment: Yes, I know all that. But I am looking to get more information out of the exception without programming each situation, and try and catch block were it could appear. Sorry for being a little vague.

Comment: @JaJa You can always write a wrapper function that opens a directory, catches the exception and throws a new kind of exception that's more to your liking.

Comment: Thanks. That could help.

Comment: @JaJa When you do this, be sure to 1) include the original exception as the Inner Exception, and 2) only catch exceptions that you can handle. Don't just catch all `Exception`s, rather only catch `DirectoryNotFoundException`, etc.

Comment: Thanks you MicroVirus, I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use try catch. Try the Code to open the file and if it throws an error run some more code instead of showing the error.

```
try
{
    // your code
}
catch(IOException ex)
{
    System.out.println (ex.toString());
    System.out.println("Could not find file " + sFileName);
}
```

Comment: Of course I can always fix my code, but then I should do that everywhere this situation could appear. That why I am asking if there is a more general way to handle this, without coding all the situations individually. Just count the number of times in your programmer life you see this exception. How much time could you save if in general, the actual directory name was ALWAYS specified in this exception.

Comment: I believe that it will need reprogramming of the KERNEL32.DLL which is highly unrecommended to change.. but this will change this particular error on your computer, for everything ;)

Comment: Thanks for answering my precise question ravenx30! I guess only microsoft can change Kernel32.dll, so I am stucked with it! :-)